# Cannot use Google Search Tools from one account in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, user-accounts, google-search, parameters

I'm using 3 accounts in Chrome<sup>*</sup>, everything works fine for 2 of them. For the 3rd (default) one, the Google Search <kbd>Tools</kbd> components are not clickable. For instance, hovering the cursor over "Any time" does nothing.

[image: Google search Tools]

What I did

- Disabled *all* extensions
- Developers tools > "Empty Cache and Hard Reload"
- Ensured Search settings are the same compared to the 2 other accounts
- Log off / back on the accounts, used only this default one

Each time closing / reopening Chrome (ensuring no chrome process remains).

Console shows "ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT"...

Could there be another setting I missed somewhere?

---

<sup>*</sup>Latest Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)
 on Ubuntu

**Edit**

Updating to Chrome 78 the problem disappeared...

Comment: Almost all sources say the same: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT means that a browser extension blocked the request. Some other sources say too many bookmarks. If the bookmarks are not to blame, I would suggest: (1) Try Incognito mode, (2) Uninstall Chrome, scrub from the disk all folders containing the string "Chrome", then reinstall Chrome and only this one account, to see what happens.

Comment: @harrymc All extensions have been disabled. 2 accounts (/3) work normally. Incognito shows the same behavior. Reinstall in the last resort (even sync-ed, a new Chrome would lose passwords and other stuff). I think it's in some settings buried deep into the account.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Bookmarks are not an issue for this user account? Chrome is supposed to save all passwords, and in any case you can save the entire profile folder, to return it if necessary (only that this might also return the problem).

Comment: 660 bookmarks. Interesting idea. On my laptop (different install), as root renamed the whole `/home/me` folder and created a new `me`. Log in: completely fresh session, and Chrome (which is btw older than my desktop Chrome since no update for a while). No sync. Just sign-in → same problem. Reported the issue to Google.

Comment: "Install" chrome portable and first the default account afterward add the other two accounts and try all three. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @Albin It's what I did, basically.

Comment: You have tried a new profile on the same computer. You have not tried to uninstall Chrome, scrub from the disk all folders containing the string "Chrome", then reinstall it.

Comment: @harrymc All in all, have been trying on 4 different computers, 3 different OSes, all Chrome had their own install at a [different] time. So no, didn't completely erase then install this week, but I consider it to be basically similar.

Comment: You are describing a situation where this one profile causes a bug or corruption in Chrome. Idea: To isolate the problem, you could create a new profile and build it up gradually, by adding bookmarks, passwords, history etc., testing on each step if restarting Chrome shows the problem. This will either uncover the problem area, or it will create a new identical profile without the glitch. In both cases, you would have either advanced in the analysis or would have fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks all, the update to Chrome 78 fixed the problem ... Question to be closed.